# Check whether a site redirects to a different URL using phantomjs giving errors for specific websites only

Tags: javascript, ajax, phantomjs

I am a newbie to frontend development and this question might be trivial. Please bear with me.

```
 var page = require('webpage').create(),
 system = require('system');

if (system.args.length === 1) {
  console.log('Usage: useragent.js <some URL>');
  phantom.exit();
}

url = system.args[1];
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.5; en-gb; HTC Desire HD A9191 Build/GRJ90) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1';
page.open(url,function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log(url+',,Unable to access network');
    } else {
            var redirectUrl = page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.URL;
            }); 
    }   
    phantom.exit();
});
```

When I run it for http://www.bebloom.com it works fine and redirects to http://mobile.bebloom.com

However, when I run it for http://www.rueducachemire.com, it gives the following error : 
    http://www.rueducachemire.com/skin/m/1382954776/js/prototype/prototype.js,/js/lib/ccard.js,/js/prototype/validation.js,/js/scriptaculous/effects.js,/js/varien/js.js,/js/varien/form.js,/js/varien/menu.js,/js/mage/translate.js,/js/mage/cookies.js,/js/droplicious.js,/j    s/seo_link_crypter.js:748
    http://www.rueducachemire.com/:173

Answer (score 1):

This is because the webpage you are trying to load has an error.

Try using

```
page.onError = function (msg, trace) {
    console.log("[ERRO]:"+msg);
    trace.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log('  ', item.file, ':', item.line);
    })
}
```

And you will know.